# LINQ Sub Query In Result Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I've the following class

```
public class Interview
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<InterviewSlot> Slots { get; set; }
}

public class InterviewSlots
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Candidate Candidate { get; set; }
}

public class Candidate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want something like this,

```
var candidates = _DbContext.Interviews.Where(i => i.Id == Id).Select(s => s.Slots.Select(c => c.Candidate).ToList();
```

**I don't want to use the InterviewSlots or the Candidate object**

I want to get all the **Candidates** in a interview.

What would the **LINQ** be for this??

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking it may be along the lines of something like this in linq:

```
var candidates = _DbContext.Interviews.Where(i => i.Id == id)
    .SelectMany(interview => interview.Slots)
    .Select(slot => slot.Candidate)
    .ToList();
```

tho, without seeing exactly how you plan to use it, quite a tricky one to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your question

> What would the LINQ be for this??

But here's what you need in order to get all candidates in an interview.

Without null checking.

```
var interview = _DbContext.Interviews.Where(i => i.Id == Id).Single();
var candidates = interview.Slots.Select(s => s.Candidate);
```

With null checking

```
var interview = _DbContext.Interviews.Where(i => i.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();
if (interview != null)
    var candidates = interview.Slots.Select(s => s.Candidate);
```

In one line

```
_DbContext.Interviews.Where(i => i.Id == Id)
                     .Single()
                        .Slots.Select(s => s.Candidate);
```